# UINavigationControllerでSwipe Backが効かない

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

現在作っているアプリで、UINavigationControllerを使っていて、

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
```

をセットしていないにもかかわらず、スワイプでバックできない問題が発生しております。

これってどういったことが原因なのでしょうか？
スワイプを無効にするは、調べるとたくさん出てくるのですが、その逆がなくて。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://appstars.jp/archive/647
にある情報では、UINavigationBarItemを書き換えたりすると
interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegateが
おかしくなるようです。

http://qiita.com/inamiy/items/fa91da40d0da53123a83
には、gestureRecognizerShouldBeginで状況に応じて
無効にする方法も書かれています。

こういうところを参考にしながら、swipe backがどのような
仕組みでどのように動作するのか、内部の動きを理解すれば、
動作しない時にどういう点を確認すべきかわかってくると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確認してみます。

Comment: 出来ました！ありがとうございます。